# Fastest way of finding common elements between two list of lists in python

Tags: python

I have a list as follows.

```
mylist = 
[  
   [  
      [  
         "chocolate_pudding",
         920.8000000000001
      ],
      [  
         "caramel_pudding",
         345.59999999999997
      ],
      [  
         "pudding",
         248.0
      ],
      [  
         "banana_pudding",
         27.599999999999998
      ]
   ],
   [  
      [  
         "biscuits",
         190.8
      ],
      [  
         "chocolates",
         33.599999999999994
      ],
      [  
         "chocolate_pudding",
         920.8000000000001
      ]
   ],
   [  
      [  
         "tiramusu",
         145.8
      ]
   ],
   [  
      [  
         "cakes",
         139.29999999999998
      ]
   ],
   [  
      [  
         "butter_cakes",
         133.0
      ]
   ],
   [  
      [  
         "chocolate_pudding",
         920.8000000000001
      ]
   ]
]
```

I want to find elements that appears more than one time in the lists (e.g., `["chocolate_pudding", 920.8000000000001]`) and want to remove the repeating ones, while keeping the very first entry.

So, my output should look like below.

```
mylist = 
[  
   [  
      [  
         "chocolate_pudding",
         920.8000000000001
      ],
      [  
         "caramel_pudding",
         345.59999999999997
      ],
      [  
         "pudding",
         248.0
      ],
      [  
         "banana_pudding",
         27.599999999999998
      ]
   ],
   [  
      [  
         "biscuits",
         190.8
      ],
      [  
         "chocolates",
         33.599999999999994
      ]
   ],
   [  
      [  
         "tiramusu",
         145.8
      ]
   ],
   [  
      [  
         "cakes",
         139.29999999999998
      ]
   ],
   [  
      [  
         "butter_cakes",
         133.0
      ]
   ]
]
```

The code I have been trying is as follows.

```
mylist_copy = mylist

for item in mylist:
    myindex = mylist.index(item)
    #print(item)

    for single_item in item:
        #print(single_item)
        for item_copy in mylist_copy:
            if mylist_copy.index(item_copy) != myindex:
                if single_item in item_copy:
                    print(single_item)
```

Since, it has many for loops I want an efficient way of doing it. Note: I also tried;

```
mylist_copy = mylist

for item in mylist:
    myindex = mylist.index(item)
    for item_copy in mylist_copy:
          if mylist_copy.index(item_copy) != myindex:
                print(set(item).intersection(item_copy))
```

However, intersection does not support lists.

Is there an easy and fast way of doing this in python?

Comment: Just fyi, your `mylist_copy = mylist` does not actually copy the list, since lists in python are mutable objects. Changing `mylist` will change `mylist_copy` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `set()` object and preserving the order of sublists:

```
mylist = [[["chocolate_pudding", 920.8000000000001], ["caramel_pudding", 345.59999999999997], 
          ["pudding", 248.0], ["banana_pudding", 27.599999999999998]], [["biscuits", 190.8], 
          ["chocolates", 33.599999999999994], ["chocolate_pudding", 920.8000000000001]], 
          [["tiramusu", 145.8]], [["cakes", 139.29999999999998]], [["butter_cakes", 133.0]], 
          [["chocolate_pudding", 920.8000000000001]]]

result, foods = [], set()
for sub_l in mylist:
    new_sublist = []
    for i in sub_l:
        if i[0] not in foods:     # on the 1st occurrence of `foodstuff` name
            new_sublist.append(i)
            foods.add(i[0])       # add `foodstuff` into set of unique foods
    if new_sublist: result.append(new_sublist)

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[[['chocolate_pudding', 920.8000000000001], ['caramel_pudding', 345.59999999999997], ['pudding', 248.0], ['banana_pudding', 27.599999999999998]], [['biscuits', 190.8], ['chocolates', 33.599999999999994]], [['tiramusu', 145.8]], [['cakes', 139.29999999999998]], [['butter_cakes', 133.0]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can unroll the inner lists and put them all in a set. Sets may not contain duplicates, so you don't even have to check for it, the set does it for you in very little time. Only caveat is that a set can not contain a list, so they need to be turned into tuples first. If you are fine with these two type conversion, it can be done in a simple set comprehension and should be reasonably fast:

```
no_duplicates = {tuple(inner) for outer in mylist for inner in outer}
```

Or you change the types back afterwards:

```
no_dupe_lists = list(map(list, no_duplicates))
```

---

You dind't ask for this, but if you want to copy a list, you have to use one of the proper copy techniques: `mylist_copy = list(mylist)` or `mylist_copy = mylist[:]` or `mylist_copy = [element for element in mylist]`, with the first one being the recomended one.

Since your list contains nested lists, those need to be copied as well though:

```
mylist_copy = [[list(inner) for inner in outer] for outer in mylist]
```

Answer (score 1):

Once a great person said, take only what you want, why delete? Now two person said :

```
mylist = [[["chocolate_pudding", 920.8000000000001], ["caramel_pudding", 345.59999999999997],
          ["pudding", 248.0], ["banana_pudding", 27.599999999999998]], [["biscuits", 190.8],
          ["chocolates", 33.599999999999994], ["chocolate_pudding", 920.8000000000001]],
          [["tiramusu", 145.8]], [["cakes", 139.29999999999998]], [["butter_cakes", 133.0]],
          [["chocolate_pudding", 920.8000000000001]]]


result=[]
track=[]
for i in mylist:
    sublist=[]
    for k in i:
        if k not in track:
            track.append(k)
            sublist.append(k)

    if sublist:

        result.append(sublist)


print(result)
```

output:

```
[[['chocolate_pudding', 920.8000000000001], ['caramel_pudding', 345.59999999999997], ['pudding', 248.0], ['banana_pudding', 27.599999999999998]], [['biscuits', 190.8], ['chocolates', 33.599999999999994]], [['tiramusu', 145.8]], [['cakes', 139.29999999999998]], [['butter_cakes', 133.0]]]
```